# Unable to validate image using Nodejs Api

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am working with Nodejs and using expressjs framework,Right now i am trying to upload image using Api but
i want two things

```
1) if image extension is not "jpg,png,gif" then error message should display
```

Here is my current code

```
var storage =   multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, './uploads');
  },
 filename: function (req, file, callback) {
     var sizeOf = require('image-size');
        var sizeOf = require('image-size');
        const originalname = file.originalname;
        const fileExt = originalname.split(".").pop();
       const excatName = originalname.split(".").slice(0, -1).join(".");
       console.log("mimetype is " + file.mimetype); // GETTING FILE EXTENSION NAME
       callback(null, excatName + "-" + Date.now().toString() + "." + fileExt);
      },
});
var upload = multer({ storage: storage }).single('userPhoto');
 const uploadavatar = function (req, res) {
    upload(req,res,function(err) {
        if(err) {
            return res.end("Error uploading file." + err);
        }
        res.end("File is uploaded");
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can pass a filter function to multer params object and with help of filter you can exclude mimetype and a create a error : -

```
var storage =   multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, './uploads');
  },
 filename: function (req, file, callback) {
     var sizeOf = require('image-size');
        var sizeOf = require('image-size');
        const originalname = file.originalname;
        const fileExt = originalname.split(".").pop();
       const excatName = originalname.split(".").slice(0, -1).join(".");
       console.log("mimetype is " + file.mimetype); // GETTING FILE EXTENSION NAME
       callback(null, excatName + "-" + Date.now().toString() + "." + fileExt);
      },
});

 var multerFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
  const memeT = file.mimetype.split('/')[1];
  const restrictToMemeType = ['jpg', 'png', 'gif'];
  if (restrictToMemeType.includes(memeT)) {
    cb(null, true);
  } else {
    cb(new Error('sorry invalid meme type'), false);
  }
};
var upload = multer({ storage: storage,fileFilter: multerFilter }).single('userPhoto');
 const uploadavatar = function (req, res) {
    upload(req,res,function(err) {
        if(err) {
            return res.end("Error uploading file." + err);
        }
        res.end("File is uploaded");
    });
};
```

Comment: @Lovenish Jain Sir, how can i get "image name" ? ( with res.end) , I want because i want to pass data to model

Comment: @prabhatmohal get it from req object ( req.file.filename)

Answer (score 0):

```
const { promisify } = require('util')
const sizeOf = promisify(require('image-size'))

var upload = multer({
  storage: multer.diskStorage({
      destination: function(req, file, callback) {
          callback(null, './uploads');
      },
      filename: function(req, file, callback) {
          let ogNameArray = file.originalname.split(".");
          callback(null, ogNameArray[0] + "-" + Date.now().toString() + "." + ogNameArray[ogNameArray.length - 1]);
      }
  })
}, {
  fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
      const filetypes = /jpeg|jpg|png|gif/;
      const extname = filetypes.test(path.extname(file.originalname).toLowerCase());
      const mimetype = filetypes.test(file.mimetype);
      if(mimetype && extname){ 
        sizeOf('./uploads/' + file.originalname)
        .then(dimensions => { 
          //validate your dimention and return true false based on this
          console.log(dimensions.width, dimensions.height) 
          cb(null, true);
        })
        .catch(err => {
          // invalid file format.
          console.error(err);
          cb(null, false);
        })        
      }else{
        cb(null, false)
      }      
  }
}, ).single('userPhoto');

const uploadavatar = function(req, res) {
  upload(req, res, function(err) {
      if (err) {
          return res.end("Error uploading file." + err);
      }
      res.end("File is uploaded");
  });
};
```

Comment: @Parshant Suthar : and how can we check/validate dimensions ?

Comment: @prabhatmohal First upload your image to any tmp folder and get the image height width if its matches then moves to the destination folder. if not then unlink and response as invalid.

Comment: is there any other solution ? because this will take time, so is there any better solution for this ?

Comment: @prabhatmohal I updated my answer with the image-size package. kindly check that solution.

Comment: Sorry but your code is not working, i can add any file ( other then mentioned extensions)

Comment: @prabhatmohal can you please post error ?

Comment: i am not getting any error but all files( every extension) is uploading

Comment: there is problem in "fileFilter" , (not working )