# Image validation not working properly using nodejs api

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am working on nodejs/expressjs and right now i am trying to validate image (dimension + extension) but not working (fileFilter not working),How can i fix this ? Where i am wrong ? Here is my current code

```
const { promisify } = require('util')
const sizeOf = promisify(require('image-size'))

var upload = multer({
  storage: multer.diskStorage({
      destination: function(req, file, callback) {
          callback(null, './uploads');
      },
      filename: function(req, file, callback) {
          let ogNameArray = file.originalname.split(".");
          callback(null, ogNameArray[0] + "-" + Date.now().toString() + "." + ogNameArray[ogNameArray.length - 1]);
      }
  })
}, {
  fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
      console.log('i am here');
      const filetypes = /jpeg|jpg|png|gif/;
      const extname = filetypes.test(path.extname(file.originalname).toLowerCase());
      const mimetype = filetypes.test(file.mimetype);
      if(mimetype && extname){ 
        sizeOf('./uploads/' + file.originalname)
        .then(dimensions => { 
          //validate your dimention and return true false based on this
          console.log(dimensions.width, dimensions.height) 
          cb(null, true);
        })
        .catch(err => {
          // invalid file format.
          console.error(err);
          cb(null, false);
        })        
      }else{
        cb(null, false)
      }      
  }
}, ).single('userPhoto');

const uploadavatar = function(req, res) {
    upload(req, res, function(err) {
      if (err) {
          return res.end("Error uploading file." + err);
      }
      res.end("File is uploaded");
  });
};
```

Comment: Could this not have been an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76041043/edit) to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76041043/283366)?

Comment: @Phil i will take care next time